# Confused about channel argument for Goroutines

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I am learning about channels and concurrency in Go and I am confused on how the code below works.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "sync/atomic"
)

var workerID int64
var publisherID int64

func main() {
    input := make(chan string)
    go workerProcess(input)
    go workerProcess(input)
    go workerProcess(input)
    go publisher(input)
    go publisher(input)
    go publisher(input)
    go publisher(input)
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
}

// publisher pushes data into a channel
func publisher(out chan string) {
    atomic.AddInt64(&publisherID, 1)
    thisID := atomic.LoadInt64(&publisherID)
    dataID := 0
    for {
        dataID++
        fmt.Printf("publisher %d is pushing data\n", thisID)
        data := fmt.Sprintf("Data from publisher %d. Data %d", thisID, dataID)
        out <- data
    }
}

func workerProcess(in <-chan string) {
    atomic.AddInt64(&workerID, 1)
    thisID := atomic.LoadInt64(&workerID)
    for {
        fmt.Printf("%d: waiting for input...\n", thisID)
        input := <-in
        fmt.Printf("%d: input is: %s\n", thisID, input)
    }
}
```

This is what I understand please correct me if I'm wrong:

***workerProcess Goroutine:***

1. *Input* channel taken as the argument which is assigned as the *in* channel.
2. In the for loop, the first printf is executed.
3. The value off the *in* channel is assigned to the variable *input*.
4. The last printf is executed to show the value of thisID and input.(This doesn't really execute till after other Goroutines run).

***publisher Goroutine:***

1. *Input* channel taken as the argument which is assigned as the *out* channel.
2. In the for loop, dataID is incremented then first printf is executed.
3. The string is assigned to data.
4. The value of data is passed to out.

**Questions:**

1. Where is the value from *out* getting passed to in the publisher Goroutine? It seems to be only in the scope of the for loop, wouldn't this cause deadlock. Since this is an unbuffered channel.
2. I don't get how the workerProcess gets the data from publisher if
   all the Goroutines in main have the arguments as the channel *input*.

   I'm used to having code written like this if the output of one function 
   is used in another:

   `foo = fcn1(input)
    fcn2(foo)`

I suspect it has something with how Goroutines run in the background but I'm not to sure I would appreciate an explanation.

3. Why isn't the last printf statement in workerProcess not executed? My guess is the channel is empty, so it's waiting for a value.

Part of the output:

```
1: waiting for input...
publisher 1 is pushing data
publisher 1 is pushing data
1: input is: Data from publisher 1. Data 1
1: waiting for input...
1: input is: Data from publisher 1. Data 2
1: waiting for input...
publisher 1 is pushing data
publisher 1 is pushing data
publisher 2 is pushing data
2: waiting for input..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have *one* channel, it is made with `make` in main.

This one single channel is named `in` in workerProcess and `out` in publisher. out is a function argument to publisher which answers question 1.

Question 2: That's the *whole* purpose of a channel. What you stuff into a channel on its input side comes out at its output side. If a function has reference to (one end of) such a channel it may communicate with someone else having reference to the same channel (its other end). What producer *send* to the channel is *received* by workerProcess. This *send* and *receive* is done through the special operator `<-` on Go. A fact you got slightly wrong in your explanation.

`out <- data` takes data and sends it through the channel named out until `<- in` reads it from the channel (remember in and out name the same channel from main). That's how workerProcess and publisher communicate.

Question 3 is a duplicate. Your whole program terminates once main is done (in your case after 1 millisecond. Nothing happens after termination of the program. Give the program more time to execute. (The non-printing is unrelated to the channel).

Comment: Great answer/summary. I have a question as well. Why would I want to use `sync/atomic` package?

Comment: @Mihailo You do not want to use sync/atomic as it is ugly, complicated and error prone. As the documentation states sync/atomic provides primitives on which you can build usable things. Sometimes the overhead of channels, selects, etc. is too high and falling back to much faster primitives is needed or sensible. Package atomic is very fast but unusable.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that. Thanks a bunch for the information, and the warning! Have a nice day.

Comment: That makes sense! I thought you had to have something like "return out" at the end of the publisher function. I've seen functions that have goroutines within them return a channel. Is it necessary to this then, since the goroutine is going to be sending values to the channel anyways.

Comment: @DanT29, returning a channel is common when there is a single producer that produces an unbounded amount of data. https://play.golang.org/p/nTvZrq92q0X